Stopping previous call of a function, if another call is made within 500ms
I want to add a feature to this code that if i set  a timer for 500ms whenever onValueChange is called and if it is called before those 500ms, it is called again and it stops the previous call execution.
Code
private _initializeProjectList(): void {
    this.loadAuthUserData$ = this._store.select(selectAuthUserSuccess);
    let uuid = '';
    this.loadAuthUserData$.pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$)).subscribe((response: UserAuthorizations | null) => {
      uuid = response !== null ? response.uuid : '';
    });
    const _object: ProjectFleetListRequestModel = {
      limit: this.limit,
      offset: this.offset,
      filter: this.searchValue,
      isFavorite: this.isActive ? true : false,
      userUuid: uuid
    };
    this.projectFleetListData$ = this._store.select(
      selectProjectFleetListSuccess
    );
    this._store.dispatch(
      Action.loadingProjectFleetListtPayload({
        reqPayload: _object
      })
    );
    this.projectFleetListData$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
    .subscribe((data) => {
      if(data?.response) {
        this.total = data.totalCount ?? 0;
        this.projectArray = data.response ?? [];
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }

onValueChange(value: string): void {
  this.searchValue = value;
  this._initializeProjectList();
}

Case: When I type AAA non-stop, it first makes call for A, then for AA, and then for AAA. I want if i type AAA in a flow, it makes calls only for AAA.

Try debounceTIme from rxjs/operators for the reset of function when actions come in between.
But you first need to notice that, when we write code outside of the subscribe which depends on data inside the subscribe, the bottom code executes before the code inside the subscribe is completed, this is due to synchronous and asynchronous code. So we should be aware of this.
Instead of using multiple subscribe, we need to convert the entire flow to a stream, a great way to chain multiple API, is to use  a switchMap which will switch from one API to another.
Then we create a subject, whose purpose is to notify the subscribe on the ngOnInit that the call needs to be made, here we debounceTime to debounce the event to 250 ms.
export class App {
  private subject = new Subject();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subject.pipe(
      takeUntil(this._destroyed$),
      debounceTime(250),
      switchMap(() => this._initializeProjectList())
    ).subscribe();
  }

  private _initializeProjectList(): void {
    this.loadAuthUserData$ = this._store.select(selectAuthUserSuccess);
    let uuid = '';
    return this.loadAuthUserData$
      .pipe(
        switchMap((response: UserAuthorizations | null) => {
          const uuid = response !== null ? response.uuid : '';
          const _object: ProjectFleetListRequestModel = {
            limit: this.limit,
            offset: this.offset,
            filter: this.searchValue,
            isFavorite: this.isActive ? true : false,
            userUuid: uuid,
          };
          this.projectFleetListData$ = this._store.select(
            selectProjectFleetListSuccess
          );
          this._store.dispatch(
            Action.loadingProjectFleetListtPayload({
              reqPayload: _object,
            })
          );
          return this.projectFleetListData$
            .pipe(tap((data) => {
              if (data?.response) {
                this.total = data.totalCount ?? 0;
                this.projectArray = data.response ?? [];
                this.loading = false;
              }
            })
            );
        }),
        );
  }

  onValueChange(value: string): void {
    this.subject.next('');
  }
}


Tried this. But still not working :(

this is saying that it is expecting 1 argument in next()

@Noobmaster619 try now
